# Accesing GPIO input via Capacitance sensor using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi good people out there! I'm new in to this subject, and need some help. I'm trying to write a little domotica project where I can switch some relays via Raspberry_2 GPIO pins using a capacitance touch sensor (SainSmart TTP223B) and GUI widgets as well. My GUI part works perfectly but when I try to add this module and run the app my GUI doesn't show at all, but touching the sensor I do hear relay working. I thing there is a problem with "While" statement but can't figure out what is wrong. here is a sample of this troubling code:

```
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

prevState = False
currState = False
while True:
    time.sleep(0.3)
    prevState = currState
    currState = GPIO.input(22)
    if currState != prevState:                    
        GPIO.setup(25,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(25,False)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        GPIO.output(25,True)
```

Comment: GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

prevState = False
currState = False
while True:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        prevState = currState
        currState = GPIO.input(22)
        if currState != prevState:
                
                GPIO.setup(25,GPIO.OUT)
                GPIO.output(25,False)
                time.sleep(0.3)
                GPIO.output(25,True)

Comment: You appear to have written part of your question in a comment. Please [edit] your post to fix this.